# Capturing image 1920x1080 with 15mp using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, photo

Im studying OpenCV using a webcam C920. This webcam has resolution 1920x1080. In webcam specifications says that C920 can capture imagens with 15mp. Using OpenCV to capture images, a picture has 2mp. Using Logitech application a picture has 15MP.

My doubts:

- How its possible capture images with 15mp with resolution 1920x1080? Is the image enlarged?
- Is it possible capture images with 15mp using OpenCV?

Images enlarged:

Using OpenCV
[image: Image captured using OpenCV]

Using Logitech application
[image: Image captured using Logitech application]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920/specs

Optical Resolution  True:3MP
Software Enhanced:15MP

i'm guessing the software is up scaling the image and performing some kind of interpolation between the pixels.

Comment: Exactly. If it had an actual 15 MP sensor, they wouldn't market it as just FullHD and the price would be somewhere else too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a similar interpolation to obtain a larger (but blurrier) output image, you can do this:

```
resized_img = cv2.resize(img, (5168, 2907), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

This may give similar quality, depending on the actual method logitech uses. More information on the various interpolation methods can be found here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Answer (score 1):

NateTheGrate, you're right, doing the resize the result is the same. Thank you.

Result after resize:

[image: Result after resize]